# $ErrorActionPreference ignored by New-SmbShare

Tags: powershell

Setting `$ErrorActionPreference` to `Stop` seems to be ignored by `New-SmbShare` in specific use cases:

- Run within Windows ISE: **No problem**
- Invoked using powershell.exe -File argument: **No problem**
- Called with explicit -ErrorAction Stop: **No problem**
- Run within PowerShell Prompt (dot-sourced): **$ErrorActionPreference is ignored**
- Invoked using powershell.exe -Command argument: **$ErrorActionPreference is ignored**

This can be tested with the following script (test.ps1):

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop" 
New-SmbShare -Name "Test" -Path "C:\NonExistingPath" 
Write-Host "Should not be reached"
```

The following call shows the error "The system cannot find the file specified", but **also** shows "Should never be reached", which is incorrect:

```
powershell.exe -Command .\test.ps1
```

The following call just throws the "The system cannot find the file specified" exception, which is correct:

```
powershell.exe -File .\test.ps1
```

Tested with:

- PowerShell 4 and 5
- Windows Server 2012 R2

Am I missing something here, or is this a PowerShell bug? I've already raised a [uservoice](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/18574045-bug-erroractionpreference-ignored-by-new-smbshar), but maybe you have an explanation?

Comment: different behaviors in different host's is a bit confusing but I have a feeling this may be a terminating/non-terminating error problem - https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/09/16/understanding-non-terminating-errors-in-powershell/

Comment: @MikeGaruccio: Yes, but New-SmbShare (or the CIM-wrapper) seems to handle it wrong. `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` should make all errors terminating errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odd you're the only person who seems to have noticed this issue.

I ran into this while calling one script from another in Powershell ISE. The script I was calling had `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` defined inside but was ignored.

I tried to find source code online and failing to do so I went to look at the module files in `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\SmbShare` and discovered that `New-SmbShare` and family are [CIM-based Cmdlet Definition XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/wmi_v2/cdxml-overview) (CDXML) cmdlets (that I'd not heard of before).

After looking into it, it seems to be an issue of variable scoping with "script" modules. The functions of the module can't see `$ErrorActionPreference`. Setting `$Global:ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` gives the correct behavior as does setting `-ErrorAction Stop` directly on the cmdlet.

I believe [this thread](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4568) represents the ongoing discussion of the issue.